# How deserialize json List<string> data in JsonResult MVC

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying deserialize json string to MyModel but get "Error" from my Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true,
                    url: '/Employee/Extract',
                    data: {data: arrToServer},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("good");
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
```

My json is:"`[{\"CategoryId\":\"1\",\"EnteredDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"SystemDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"EmpId\":\"1\",\"ProductId\":\"9\"},{\"CategoryId\":\"1\",\"EnteredDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"SystemDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"EmpId\":\"1\",\"ProductId\":\"9\"},{\"CategoryId\":\"1\",\"EnteredDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"SystemDate\":\"15.02.2014\",\"EmpId\":\"1\",\"ProductId\":\"9\"}]"`

My JsonResult:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Extract()
        {
List<string> myDeserializedObjList = (List<string>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["data"], typeof(List<string>));
            return Json("111");
        }
or get a "Good" when my JsonResult is empty:
public JsonResult Extract(List<string> data)
        {
            return Json("111");
        }
```

My model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string EnteredDate { get; set; }
    public string SystenDate { get; set; }
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: return Json("111"); wont return valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

1. Type of parameter in action should be `List<MyModel>`, instead `List<string>`.
2. ContentType in `jQuery.ajax` should be application/json in your case.

By default `jQuery.ajax` contentType is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This means that parameters sent in url string. You should change contentType in `jQuery.ajax` to application/json and convert your js object to json with `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    url: '/Employee/Extract',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({data: arrToServer}),        
    success: function (result) {
        alert("good");
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: "thanks", I got empId, but I changed code from JsonResult to ActionResult, why ajax return "Error"? My new code: `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Extract()
        {
            List<MyModel> myDeserializedObjList = (List<MyModel>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["data"], typeof(List<MyModel>));
            foreach (MyModel model in myDeserializedObjList)
            {
                int empId = model.EmpId;
                ViewBag.empID = empId;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }`

Comment: @okrupovich because, in your code, jQuery.ajax expect json result (dataType: 'json'), but in action your return html. If you return html, you should change dataType to 'html'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `List<MyModel>` instead of `List<string>`.

Comment: if I'm using List<MyModel> - data Count = 0

Comment: Try to use `data: arrToServer` instead of `data: {data: arrToServer}` in your Ajax request configuration. Also, I'm not very familiar with Newtonsoft.Json, so try it with `[HttpPost] public JsonResult Extract(List<MyModel> data) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the JSON de-serialization manually. The ASP.NET MVC runtime will do it for you. You will have to make a few corrections/changes:

First get your ajax call right. Define `contentType` and pass the data array correctly.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                url: '/Employee/Extract',
                data: JSON.stringify(arrToServer), // stringify array
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',   // define content type
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("good");
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

At your controller, you can simply get the data via parameters:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult<string> Extract(MyModel[] modelArray)
    {
        // voila! , modelArray has contents you passed from JavaScript
        return Json("111");
    }
```